# Mean Stack: When using $http "Post" with Angular, req.body in Express contains additional {} and saving it to mongod does not work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to post data from Angular and save it in MongoDB through Express and Mongoose.

**myConfig file**

```js
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var parser = require('body-parser');
var router = require('./api');
var app = express();

require('./database');

app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(parser.json());
app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("Evalyst is running on port 3000");
});
```

**myController**

```js
$scope.addNewEvaluation = function (newEvaluation) {
   dataService.addNewEvaluation(newEvaluation);
   $scope.closeModal();
};
```

**MyService**

```js
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/evaluations',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: {'evaluation': newEvaluation}
  }).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

**My backend (node.js, express, mongoose)**

```js
router.post('/evaluations', function (req, res) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");

  var evaluation = req.body;
  console.log(evaluation);

  Evaluation.create(evaluation, function (err, evaluation) {
     if (err) {
         return res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
     }
     res.json({evaluation, message: "Evaluation created"});
  });
});
```

The problem is that an empty object is saved in my MongoDB.

In my req.body, I have the following line:

```js
  body: { '{"evaluation":{"title":"Sports","description":"Just do it","notifFreq":"daily"}}': '' },
```

I don't understand why I get the evaluation wrapped in **{'**  **}' : ''}**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send it like this

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/evaluations',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: newEvaluation
}).success(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
}).error(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

because your newEvaluation is already an object.

Comment: I still get the same issue in my req.body : 'body: { '{"title":"Sports","description":"Just do it","notifFreq":"daily"}': '' },
'

Comment: Maybe this will work 
$http.post(url, newEvaluation)
                        .success(function (data) {console.log(data); }

Comment: Let me see your newEvaluation  from client side plz.

Comment: console.log(newEvaluation) in my service : 'Object {title: "MyTitle", description: "MyDescription", notifFreq: "daily"}'

Comment: app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));   
app.use(parser.json());
try to change this lines
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

Comment: Change lines orders.

Comment: It did not change anything. Still have the same issue. It is like I have my object as the key and I have an empty value.

Comment: Its really weird.

Comment: I think I found the problem. To send my data using different servers, I am using the content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. However, I thing I need to use the content-type: application/json. Is there a way to set those two content-types ?

Answer (score 0):

Your newEvaluation data is a string.

```
'{"evaluation":{"title":"Sports","description":"Just do it","notifFreq":"daily"}}': ''
```

Please send javascript object to backend. Split your string first by ":" character and then parse json string to json object.

```
$scope.addNewEvaluation = function (newEvaluation) {
   var splitStr = newEvaluation.split(":")[0],
   newEvaluationObj = JSON.parse(splitStr);      
   dataService.addNewEvaluation(splitStr);
   $scope.closeModal();
};
```

Comment: I did not manage to run it. I always get error messages like : split is not a function or JSON error.

Comment: can you console.log newEvaluation. What is printed?

Comment: I think I found the problem. To send my data using different servers, I am using the content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. However, I thing I need to use the content-type: application/json. Is there a way to set those two content-types ?

Comment: data: '',
headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
}